# Difference b/w pg_basebackup and TAR backup (stop/start) backup in PostgreSQL 9.3?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, database-backups

Please if someone can explain me on major difference b/w pg_basebackup and tar backup (start/stop backup) in PG. I've read somewhere that pg_basebackup can not be used when it comes to user managed tablespace (non-default tablespace), however I'm not sure about this as I can backup user managed tablespaces too using pg_basebackup tool.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods do roughly the same, and both are intended to backup the entire cluster with all tablespaces.

What you call "tar backup" works like this:

1. Call `pg_start_backup()`;
2. Copy all files ($PGDATA, tablespaces) and necessary WAL logs using any tool you like (cp, tar, rsync, etc.);
3. Call `pg_stop_backup()`.

`pg_basebackup` makes it bit easier, but internally it just performs the same steps for your.

Read these two sections from the documentation for details: [Making a Base Backup](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-BASE-BACKUP) and [Making a Base Backup Using the Low Level API](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-LOWLEVEL-BASE-BACKUP).